# Как отправить значение текстового поля вместе с файлом через Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Отправляю Ajax-ом файл. Вместе с ним хочу отправить текстовое поле `name_file`. 
Как это сделать?

Форма:

```
<input type="text" name="name_file" value="" placeholder="Введите имя файла" />
<br/>
<input id="sortpicture" type="file" name="sortpic" />
<button id="upload">Upload</button>
```

Скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#upload').on('click', function() {
        $(".load_form").css('display', 'none');
        var file_data = $('#sortpicture').prop('files')[0];
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', file_data);
        alert(form_data);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(php_script_response) {
                alert(php_script_response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: вообще конструктор `FormData` принимает в себя форму. то есть достаточно было вообще `new FormData($('form_selector').serialize())`

Comment: Странно тут то, что вы **уже** проделали **ту самую** операцию, но с другим полем `form_data.append('file', file_data);`, о которой спрашиваете в вопросе О_о

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно просто в `form_data` добавить ещё одну пару ключ-значение:

```
<input id="filename" type="text" placeholder="Введите имя файла" />
```

---

```
form_data.append('file_name', $("#filename").val());
```

[Пример в fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vs6hc88x/)

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек, сработало.

Answer (score 0):

Смотря на то, как устроен Ваш обьект FormData(), попробуйте так:

```
data: form_data.name,
```

Если не поможет, давайте код класса FormData().